# What type of anchor should I use for ceiling hook for ceiling fan?

Tags: anchor

Going to install a ceiling fan, may I know what type of anchor bolt/sleeve to install ceiling hook?

Yes is a norm.

Location : Singapore

Ceiling Hook
http://www.kdk.sg/ceiling-hook.html

Answer (score 2):

I would not attempt to hang a ceiling fan with an anchor. It would be much better if you located a ceiling joist and screwed directly into it.

Answer (score 2):

The [instructions for a fan made by that manufacturer](http://www.kdk.sg/usermanuals/M48SG_M60SG.pdf) make it clear that you should choose the fixing according to the structure of your ceiling.

If you have a concrete ceiling, you should use concrete anchor bolts of the type and size specified in the installation guide for whatever fan you are installing.

The instructions give the diameter and length. They look like typical expansion bolts for use in concrete. If in doubt take a print of the instructions to the hardware store to aid in selecting bolts.

If you do not have a concrete ceiling you'll need different types of bolts.

Even with a concrete ceiling you need to be sure it is OK to drill holes into it.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't want to criticise, but please do NOT blow concrete dust out of a hole in the ceiling!  Is there no Health & Safety in the far east at all?!

Comment: @Grim It is completely common and normal to use a vacuum, compressed air, etc. to do this even in the US.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk Wow - we're not even supposed to go near concrete or cement dust without a mask on these days in the UK!  On the other hand, Health & Safety really has gone mad...

Comment: @Grim Yea...you probably should wear a mask and any relevant eye protection...and a vacuum is generally a better idea than blowing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you live? In North America, you attach a ceiling fan to a ceiling fan electrical box. A ceiling fan electrical box is an electrical box with a metal arm that attaches between two ceiling joists. This provides a solid support for a moving fan.

I've never heard of attaching a ceiling fan to a 'hook' like that, but maybe that is normal in other regions of the world.